# im creating a chat bot with AI for my business in instagram

Tags: node.js, instagram, instagram-api

I'm creating a chatbot with AI for my Instagram business. I'm using Node.js to connect with Instagram and OpenAI. My current problem is that I'm using a non-official API for Instagram (instagram-private-api). My question is whether there is any way to accomplish this using the official API of Instagram (the Facebook API). I couldn't find information on how to access that API and use it in Node.js. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

personally i don't have experience with the instagram and facebook APIs. but i do have experience in making chatbots, i suggest you use botpress (my personal favourite) it's really simple and there are alot of resources out there on the internet where you can learn botpress.
hope this helps :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).